# How to sort a linked list with objects and private variables

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, private, setter

I am going to be honest and up front here. This is homework, but I have become desperate and am looking for anyone to assist me. I have been working on this off and on for over a month and have gone to my instructor multiple times. Basically this program needs to create and sort a linked list that has an int, string and double in each node. It needs to be able to sort by each data type as well as print in input order but once I figure one out I can transfer it to the other data types. Please, everything needs to be "hand made", please do not use any built in commands as I need to create everything as per my instructor's demands.

I attempted to make the linked list and then sort it, but I ran into a problem so I decided to try and sort the list as I create it.

For example: Input the first node, then input the next node in front/behind the first, then put the next where it needs to go... and so forth.

Here is my code (I only focus on the strings):

```
    String repeat = "y";
    list1 fChr = null;
    list1 p = fChr;
    list1 copy = null;
    //list1 dCopy = null;
    //list1 iCopy = null;
    list1 fd = fChr;//front of the double list
    list1 fi = fChr;//front of the integer list
    list1 fStr = fChr;//front of the string list~
    list1 pStr = fStr;
    boolean inserted = false;
    int iii = 0;
    String sss = "";
    double ddd = 0.0;
    while(repeat.equals("y"))//while the user agrees to adding a new node
    {            
        if(fChr == null)// if the front is empty
        {
            fChr = new list1();//create a new node by calling object and sets it as the front
            p = fChr;
            copy = fChr;
            sss = fChr.GetS();
            iii = fChr.GetI();
            ddd = fChr.GetD();
            copy.SetS(sss);
            copy.SetI(iii);
            copy.SetD(ddd);
            System.out.println("(1)");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("(2)");
            if(p!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("p = "+ p.GetS());
                if(p.next != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("p.next = "+ p.next.GetS());
                    System.out.println("p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
                }
            }

            p = fChr;
            while(p.next != null)//finds the end of the Linked list
            {
                System.out.println("(3)");
                p = p.next;//moves the pointer p down the list
            }
            list1 NextNode = new list1();//
            p.next = NextNode;
            sss = NextNode.GetS();
            iii = NextNode.GetI();
            ddd = NextNode.GetD();
            copy = NextNode;
            String gg = "hi";//tests to see if the setter is actually   changing the value inside copy(it is not, it prints b) 
            copy.SetS(gg);
            copy.SetI(iii);
            copy.SetD(ddd);
            System.out.println(copy.GetS());
            System.out.println("p = "+ p.GetS());

        }

        pStr = fStr;
        //System.out.println(copy.GetS()+"*");
        inserted = false;
        if(fStr == null)
        {
            System.out.println("(4)");
            fStr = copy;//fStr = fChr;
            inserted = true;
            //System.out.println("p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
        }
        else if(copy.GetS().compareTo(fStr.GetS()) < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("(5)");
            //System.out.println("1)p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
            copy.next = fStr;//ERROR ON THIS LINE
            System.out.println("2)p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
            System.out.println("fChr.next: "+fChr.next.GetS());
            fStr = copy;
            System.out.println("3)p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
            inserted = true;
            System.out.println("p = "+ p.GetS());
            System.out.println("p.next = "+ p.next.GetS());
            System.out.println("4)p.next.next = "+ p.next.next.GetS());
        }
        else if(fStr.next == null && fStr != null)
        {
            System.out.println("(6)");
            fStr.next = copy;
            inserted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("(7)");
            pStr = fStr;
            System.out.println("RIP (8)");
            while(pStr.next != null && inserted == false)
            {
                System.out.println("(9)");
                System.out.println("RIP");
                if(copy.GetS().compareTo(pStr.next.GetS()) < 0)//if it goes between 2 nodes
                {
                    System.out.println("(10)");
                    copy.next = pStr.next;
                    pStr.next = copy;
                    inserted = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("(11)");
                    pStr = pStr.next;
                }
                if(pStr.next == null && inserted == false)// it goes at the end(not necessary bc of the (in order) part)
                {
                    System.out.println("(12)");
                    pStr.next = copy;
                } 

            }
        }
        repeat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to add a node [y/n]");
        System.out.println("End of Loop");
    }
    System.out.println(fStr.GetS());
    PrintMenu(fChr, fi, fd, fStr);// sends the user to the menu screen
}
```

From all of my print statements I have (what I think) found the problem. This code runs through twice and upon hitting "y" for the third time, prints "(3)" in an infinite loop. I have found that (say the input for the strings is "c" then "b") "p" is equal to "c", p.next is equal to "b" and p.next.next is equal to "c". So, p is in an infinite loop. I have no idea why it does this, I have a theory that it could be because the front(fChr) changes and then "p" points to it and is just kinda drug along. I also just realized that me trying to set "copy" equal to "NextNode" was unsuccessful and copy just holds the value inside p.next(which is NextNode). That seems correct, but when I try to put something else in, it doesn't work. I could be testing this incorrectly and in that case the setter is correct. Setting is one of the main problems that I seem to be having. I will try to answer as many questions as I can if anyone has any.

Also here is the object in case you would like to see it. Thank you for your time, any help will be appreciated. Please if possible try to keep it relatively simple this is a high school assignment and I am so close and am stumped on how to fix what is wrong. Also, you may have noticed, but I have to use private variables. I am not asking for someone to give me a program that works, I am just asking if you know why what is going wrong is happening and if you know how to fix it. Thank you from the bottom of my heart!

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class list1
    {
    private int i;
    private String s;
    private double d;
    private String ss = null;
    private int ii = 0;
    private double dd = 0.0;
    list1 next = null; 
        public list1()
        {
        String str;
        s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String");
        String temp =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an Integer");
        i = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        String temp2 =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Double");
        d = Double.parseDouble(temp2);

        }

        public double GetD()
        {  
            return d;
        }

        public String GetS()
        {   
            return s;
        }

        public int GetI()
        {
            return i;
        }

        public void SetS(String x)
        {
            ss = x;
        }

        public void SetI(int y)
        {
            ii = y;
        }

        public void SetD(double z)
        {
            dd = z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `copy`?  Are you trying to create a copy of a list node?  If you are, then statements like `copy = fChr` and `copy = NextNode` won't do it.  Those cause `copy` to point to the _same_ node as `fChr` or `NextNode`.  Then when you say `copy.next = fStr`, it will also set `fChr.next = fStr` or `NextNode.next = fStr` depending on what `copy` was assigned to, since `copy` is a reference to the same node.  If you really want to make a copy with the same fields, try `copy = new list1();`, which will create a new node; I think you're already setting the fields up.

Comment: @ajb Ok thank you, and you are right I was trying to copy a list node. The only thing is that I have my questions of "input a string, double and int" in the object.         copy = new list1()        will ask those questions again,correct? I want to copy NextNode without creating a new  instance of the object(the questions). Is there anyway that I can do this or am I going to have to completely rework the program?

Comment: Yuck, I didn't see that.  That's really not a good place to put those input statements.  Suggestion: add a `static` method in the `list1` class, `public static list1 createListNodeFromInput()` that creates a new node, then asks the user your questions and sets the fields.  Then the rest of your program uses `node = list1.createListNodeFromInput()` when it wants to create a new node from the user's data, and `node = new list1()` when it just wants to create a new node, in preparation for making a copy of another node (for example).

Comment: P.S. If I had a lot of time to sit down with you, I'd suggest a whole lot more reorganizations of your code.  But this is a fairly simple fix that you can do without tearing up your whole program.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that and will see if I can get it to work. The problem is that my teacher hates static variables, I'm not sure if this is the same thing. If it is I may just have to try and figure out another way or just hope he doesn't mind too much. My teacher is old fashioned and says in college they won't care but he wants us to understand everything with no shortcuts which i guess is respectable.

Comment: @ajb so how would I make a copy of "node" then, because I need 1 for the chronological list and 1 for the string list?

Comment: Static variables and static methods aren't the same thing.  Static variables (other than `final` variables which are constants) are generally considered a bad idea, except _maybe_ for some specific use cases.  I won't go into the reasons why they're bad, but those reasons don't apply to static methods, which are generally acceptable.  Static _factory_ methods, where you have a method that returns the class that you can use in lieu of a constructor, are 100% acceptable.  My suggestion is one of those.

Comment: To make a copy of the node, use `new` (`new list1()`), then use the getters and setters to read fields from one node and set them in the new node.  I think you were already doing the last part of that.  Just copy the data fields.  Don't copy `next`, because then you'll have nodes from one list pointing to nodes in another list and you will run into major troubles.

Comment: Also, I just noticed: why do you have two copies of each field?  If `GetD` returns `d` and `SetD` returns `dd`, then the getter isn't returning the same thing that the setter sets.  You're never using `dd`, `ss`, and `ii`.  Please get rid of them.

Comment: @ajb Ok, thank you!! I just took out the second field and that "set("hi")" test that I had in my code and it worked! it printed "hi" so i will work on my code further now that I know that my copy nodes work...I think. Anyways i very much appreciate the help :)